# Nginx Access-Control-Allow-Origin not working

Tags: ajax, nginx

Trying to access my API via Ajax and I'm getting this error:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9090' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

My NGINX configuration looks like this and I'm using Varnish too.

```
server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:8080;
    server_name api.example.cc;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/api.access.log combined;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/api.error.log;

    root /home/spark/api.example.cc/web;
    #index index.php;
    try_files $uri /index.php;

    set $cache_uri $request_uri;
    location / {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://localhost:9090';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Authorization';
    }
}
```

curl -X OPTIONS -i http://api.example.cc results:

```
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
Server: nginx/1.8.0
Date: Wed, 30 Dec 2015 20:14:27 GMT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Authorization
Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000
Content-Type: text/plain charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 0
X-Varnish: 65550
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish-v4
Connection: keep-alive
```

curl -X GET/POST -i http://api.example.cc results:

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Server: nginx/1.8.0
Date: Wed, 30 Dec 2015 20:23:17 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 168
X-Varnish: 32823
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish-v4
Connection: keep-alive

<html>
<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>403 Forbidden</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.8.0</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you see headers with `curl -X OPTIONS -i http://127.0.0.1:8080` and GET/POST

Comment: just updated the question with the info. Thanks

Comment: Have you called GET and POST separately with curl? You should get 403.  Is ajax req working with the same origin (domain)?

Comment: And if same origin ajax works, show how you make CORS from js?

Comment: Yes, called separately and both gave me 403. Different domains. With this config I get 405 Not Allowed for OPTIONS, I have changed while talking to you and got 204. Do you have any example of nginx config ?

Comment: http://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html

Comment: Invoke `curl` again (OPTIONS, POST, GET), but with the same url as you want to make ajax

Comment: HTTP/1.1 204 No Content for OPTIONS, 403 for GET and POST. I'm calling the public URL which Ajax will use.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99344/discussion-between-kwarunek-and-gijow).

Answer (score 9):

config

```
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://localhost:9090';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Authorization';
```

before "location / {...}" helps me

Answer (score 2):

For others facing this same type of issue, you should also resolve the `404` error before troubleshooting the lack of `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers.

If the web server can't find the requested resource, then that means your application code is never executed and the headers are never set. The default `404` error response is returned by the web server, which does not contain `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers.

When you resolve the `404` error, your application code gets executed which should set the response headers as needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running in 404 error after doing cors configuration or can't bypass cors security policy accessing your api via ajax, you can try using this nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:8080;
    server_name api.example.cc;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/api.access.log combined;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/api.error.log;

    root /home/sites/api.cc/web;
    #index index.php;
    try_files $uri /index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
                    try_files $uri =404;
                    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;

                    # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini

                    # With php5-fpm:
                    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
                    fastcgi_index index.php;
                    include fastcgi_params;
                    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

                 if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                    more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin *' ;
                    #
                    # Om nom nom cookies
                    #
                    more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true';
                    more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                    #
                    # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
                    #
                    more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Authorization';
                    # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
                    #
                    more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
                    more_set_headers 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
                    more_set_headers 'Content-Length' 0;
                    return 204;
             }
            if ($request_method = 'POST') {
                    more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin *' ;
                    more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true';
                    more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Authorization';
                    more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            }
            if ($request_method = 'GET') {
                    more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin *' ;
                    more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true';
                    more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Authorization';
                    more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods GET, POST, OPTIONS';
            }
    }
```

}

to install `more_set_headers` in your nginx use `apt-get install nginx-extras`

Hope it helps

Comment: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin *' is insecure, you should replace the * with the proper origin.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue. In my case, I was able to resolve it by providing the correct `Content-Type`. I know it might seem unrelated, but my use-case was also pretty unique.

I wanted to set up a CORS proxy which basically means, you want to pass all requests from the browser through a server who's only job is to forward those requests to an external server and parrot back the corresponding responses, as the browser is unable to make the direct requests on its own (CORS in a nutshell).

Once I fixed the `Content-Type`, my browser started making an `OPTION` call before making a `POST` call which had all the right headers set. The whole issue might have happened because my request was conveyed to the external server which returned a 4xx status in response, and as as result Nginx ignored setting the response headers (?) Just a hunch.

Comment: where do you provide the content-type, and how do you know what to set it to?

Comment: @redOctober13 You can provide it as part of the HTTP headers in the request you are making to nginx.